# Are there mapping utilities out there that will let me import geo position data (lat/long) and plot the points on a map?

Tags: geolocation, google-maps

I have a data file with a bunch of lat/long positions.  Is there any mapping software out there (google maps, etc) that will allow me to import the positions from the file and plot them on a map?  I would be this can be done through google maps but I'm not sure how to do it.  I just want something that I can use quickly with a minimal amount of programming to do.  I don't need to annotate anything.  Just view where the points are on the map.  I'm just wondering if there is something already available out there to import into google maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For overlaying your own data on google maps and not installing anything:

- Use GPS Data Team's Points of Interest conversion page to convert [CSV to KML](http://garmin.gps-data-team.com/poi_manager.php) (one of [many possible conversions](http://www.gps-data-team.com/convert.php))
- then visit http://www.google.com/mapmaker and [add your KML](http://maps.google.ca/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=155420).

For download and install software, ESRI's free [ArcGIS Explorer](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer/index.html) can add CSV files, as well as some [other formats](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisexplorer/900/en/add_map_content_files.htm). If you're partial to open source there are also [uDig](http://udig.refractions.net/) and [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) which can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Google Earth pro can import CSV files with lat/long or vector data.